# "Il était" and "Ce n’était que" in Perrault's Barbe-Bleue

Tags: expressions

The question is on the highlighted phrases in these opening paragraphs of Perrault's Barbe-Bleue.

> **Il était** une fois un homme qui avait de belles maisons à la ville et à la campagne, de la vaisselle d’or et d’argent, des meubles en broderie et des carrosses tout dorés ; mais par malheur cet homme avait la barbe bleue : cela le rendait si laid et si terrible, qu’il n’était ni femme ni fille qui ne s’enfuît de devant lui.
>      
>   Une de ses voisines, dame de qualité, avait deux filles parfaitement belles. Il lui en demanda une en mariage, et lui laissa le choix de celle qu’elle voudrait lui donner. Elles n’en voulaient point toutes deux, et se le renvoyaient l’une à l’autre, ne pouvant se résoudre à prendre un homme qui eût la barbe bleue. Ce qui les dégoûtait encore, c’est qu’il avait déjà épousé plusieurs femmes, et qu’on ne savait ce que ces femmes étaient devenues.
>      
>   Barbe-Bleue, pour faire connaissance, les mena avec leur mère, et trois ou quatre de leurs meilleures amies, et quelques jeunes gens du voisinage, à une de ses maisons de campagne, où on demeura huit jours entiers. **Ce n’était que** promenades, que parties de chasse et de pêche, que danses et festins, que collations : on ne dormait point, et on passait toute la nuit à se faire des malices les uns aux autres ; enfin tout alla si bien, que la cadette commença à trouver que le maître du logis n’avait plus la barbe si bleue, et que c’était un fort honnête homme. Dès qu’on fut de retour à la ville, le mariage se conclut.

**Question**

They both seem to say *there were*, but one has *il* in it and the other *ce*.

1. Are they interchangeable--so that either could have begun with *il* or *ce*?
2. Assuming no to 1, what are the general rules on when to use *il* and when *ce*?  (For example, *Il était* coming at the very outset of the story or *c'était* having *ne que* to go with it, do these have anything to do with the choice?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Il était une fois' is the french equivalent of 'once upon a time'. The il doesn't refer to anything and is used in a general sense, like in 'il pleut' (it's raining).
'Ce n'était que', on the other hand, means "it was only", and the ce refers specifically to that eight day stay, which was only walks, hunting, fishing, etc...

So no, they are not interchangeable.